# Setting a child's name with string on Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, set

I am using this code in Firebase to save players stats (currently only name) to database:

```
var usersRef = ref.child("users");
var userid = kongregate.services.getUserId();
usersRef.set({
    userid: {
        name: kongregate.services.getUsername(),
    }
});
```

What I am trying to do in here is i am trying to add user's id as a new child of "users". But i am getting "userid" instead of userid variable that i declared at top. How can i make a child with userid variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a variable as a property name.

A few solutions:

```
var users = {};
users[userid] = { name: kongregate.services.getUsername() };
usersRef.set(users);
```

This will set the right value, but will also overwrite all other data at `users`.

A better approach is likely:

```
var user = { name: kongregate.services.getUsername() };
usersRef.child(userid).set(user);
```

Or even at a lower level:

```
usersRef.child(userid).child(name).set(kongregate.services.getUsername());
```